# Comma after last selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given this code

```css
a,
h1
{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

I would like to rewrite it such that each selector ends with a comma, even the last. This will make it easy to add or reorder selectors. However if I add a comma after the last the style will not be applied. This code seems to work

```css
a,
h1,
_ {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

but could this cause unforseen issues?

Comment: I don't think there's ever likely to be a `_` tag added to HTML, so I think it should be safe. It's valid CSS syntax, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Not as long as you don't have a `<_>` tag in your HTML..

Comment: I wouldn't do this; it's confusing. Just learn to be content writing code that won't bewilder future maintainers of your project. Always remember, *don't be clever*.

Comment: It's one key. It's right there...

Comment: @StevenPenny If you want to be lazy, write code that won't require future explanations for other developers.

Comment: What are you considering `_`symbol? An HTML tag, a class or an id?

Comment: If you considering it an HTML tag, then this is absolutely wrong declaration. W3C does not allow to write down custom tags. And if you are considering it a class or an id selector then use `.` dot or `#` symbol before the `_` symbol to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're fully aware, `_` is a completely valid type selector, so there's no reason it should be breaking your CSS rule by itself.

The only unforeseen issue that could come up with this is that, conversely, your CSS rule would apply any `_` element that happens to be added to the document(s) you're styling (for whatever reason), just as it would any other element with any other matching selector. If the specification decides to introduce an `_` element, then the meaning of your selector *with respect to the markup* completely changes. Of course, since we're talking about HTML, it's *vanishingly* unlikely, but it's still a possibility; in the unlikely, unfortunate event that it *does* happen, you will have to change that stub selector to... something else.

I won't repeat what others have stated in the comments on how sensible such a coding practice might or might not be.

Comment: It does not really matter what the “document type” (presumably, specification of a markup language) contains. Whatever is added to HTML specs does not affect the way a selector like `_` works; the only thing that matters is whether an element with the name `_` appears in a document.

Comment: @Jukka: I was sort of implying that the introduction of such an element into the document language specification would lead to the usage of that element in documents, as it would then be considered conforming. But you are right - it does not matter whether the specification allows it, because even in a non-conforming document the CSS rule would still take effect where applicable.

Answer (score 2):

> could this cause unforeseen issues?

Not code-wise; but consider the people. Think of the poor developer who stumbles upon this CSS. Imagine his/her mental state upon discovering *unnecessary CSS **in a stylesheet***. Gasp.

Serious reasoning: make it easy to add or reorder selectors.

- **Adding a selector** to the beginning or middle of the selector list requires typing the selector then a comma, no matter what. Adding to the end of the list requires a comma then the selector. So your underscore doesn't help there.
- **Reordering selectors** boils down to two possibilities:

  1. Moving a selector from the beginning/middle of the list to the end, then deleting the comma. But your cursor will likely already be right after that comma, so a simple tap of backspace solves your problem.
  2. Switching a pair of selectors (this process could occur multiple times, but each switch is identical).

     - If neither selector is the last selector, this isn't an issue: merely switch the entire lines.
     - In the `(n-1)/(n choose 2) * 100`% chance, where `n` is the number of selectors, that one of the selectors is the last selector, and thus has no comma, then

       1. Switch the selectors themselves (leaving the comma by the first selector alone), or
       2. Cut+paste the entire lines, and accept the fact that you'll have to add a comma after the new first selector, and delete the comma after the new last selector.

In short: I've toiled more in writing this answer than you ever will adding or reordering selectors. The underscore is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you considering it an `HTML` tag, then this is absolutely wrong declaration. **W3C** does not allow to write down custom tags. And if you are considering it a `class` or an `id` selector then use `.` dot or `#` symbol before the `_` underscore symbol to make it work.

**CSS Code:**

```
a,
h1,
._ {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8483F/)

Comment: @Steven: When you are writing an `_` underscore symbol after last valid (valid by w3c) selector css parser considering it a selector. So the defined styles applied on valid selectors `a` and `h1`. But css parser unable to find `_` underscore selector. And when you will write any other selector after `_` separating with comma then the styles will also apply on those selectors.

Comment: For more details see this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords

Comment: HTML specifications do not say anything about what you can write in CSS.

Comment: @A.K You Just Don't Get It, Do You? http://vimeo.com/24669583 I am not talking about using `_` as a selector, only a placeholder